# '!=' and '<>' operators in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

According to postgresql [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) `!=` means the same as `<>`. In reality, it doesn't seems to be the case:

```
psql=> select 1 where 1!=-1;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer !=- integer
LINE 1: select 1 where 1!=-1;
                        ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
psql=> select 1 where 1<>-1;
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

Is this a bug or this is an expected behavior that wasn't covered by the manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a space so that postgres knows, that it's a `!=` operator and not `!=-`:

```
select 1 != -1;
```

Or you can put it in parentheses:

```
select 1!=(-1);
```

Comment: So it looks like the only problem here is the postgresql parser. "select 1 from dual where 1!=-1;" in Oracle, for example, works as intended, but whatever.

Comment: postgres supports `=-` to be a part of an operator, that's why it is parsing it as a whole and doesn't recognize it

Comment: @horse_with_no_name I've corrected although postgres docs say, that: *A row constructor consists of the key word ROW, a left parenthesis, **zero or more** expressions (separated by commas) for the row field values, and finally a right parenthesis.*

Answer (score 2):

The SQL standard operator is `<>`, so it is a good habit to stick with it.

The reason for the behavior difference is explained in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createoperator.html):

> There are a few restrictions on your choice of [operator] name:
>
> - A multicharacter operator name cannot end in `+` or `-`, unless the name also contains at least one of these characters:
>
>   ~ ! @ # % ^ & | ` ?
>
>   For example, `@-` is an allowed operator name, but `*-` is not. This restriction allows PostgreSQL to parse SQL-compliant commands without requiring spaces between tokens.

Now since `<>` does not contain any of these characters, PostgreSQL knows that `<>-` cannot be an operator name, and there is no ambiguity in parsing.